# Using OData actions

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

## Versions

To use features like `$select` and `$expand` upgraded all packages WebApi and OData for pre-release versions (from [aspnetwebstack](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/)).

> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi          -> *5.0.0-beta1-130514*
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client   -> *5.0.0-beta1-130514*
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core     -> *5.0.0-beta1-130514*
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData    -> *5.0.0-beta1-130514*
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Web...   -> *5.0.0-beta1-130514*

## Controllers

I have a base class for my API controlers:

```
public class baseApiController<T> : EntitySetController<T, int>
    where T: class, IEntity, new()
{
    public IRepository Repositorio { get; private set; }
    public baseApiController(IRepository repositorio)
    {
        Repositorio = repositorio;
    }

    [Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All, PageSize=20)]
    public override IQueryable<T> Get()
    {
        return Repositorio.Query<T>();
    }

    [Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    protected override T GetEntityByKey(int key)
    {
        return Repositorio.Get<T>(key);
    }
}
```

And a **User controller**

```
[Authorize]
public class usuariosController : baseApiController<Usuario>
{
    public usuariosController(IRepository repositorio)
        : base(repositorio)
    { }

    [Authorize(Roles="Admin,TI")]
    public HttpResponseMessage post(Usuario usuario)
    {
        var x = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(usuario.Email, "maisbb", new { Nome = usuario.Nome }); //TODO: Não fixar senha
        Repositorio.Store(usuario);

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, usuario);
    }

    [HttpGet, Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    public IQueryable roles([FromODataUri] int key) 
    {
        var usuario = (from u in Repositorio.Query<Usuario>()
                    where u.Id == key
                    select new { u.Email }).SingleOrDefault();
        return Roles.GetRolesForUser(usuario.Email).AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

## Goals

An action `roles` retrieve all the roles for a specific user:
The goal is to **retrieve all roles of a user** with this URL:
`/api/usuarios(67)/roles`

I configured my API `WebApiConfig` as follows:

```
modelBuilder.EntitySet<Usuario>("usuarios");
var entityTypeUsuario = modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>();
var actRoles = entityTypeUsuario.Action("roles");
actRoles.Parameter<int>("key");
actRoles.Returns<string[]>();

...

var model = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
config.Routes.MapODataRoute(routeName: "OData", routePrefix: "api", model: model);
config.EnableQuerySupport();
var jsonFormatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
var enumConverter = new StringEnumConverter();
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(enumConverter);
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
var jqueryFormatter = config.Formatters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter));
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.FormUrlEncodedFormatter);
config.Formatters.Remove(jqueryFormatter);
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
```

## Error

GET: `/api/usuarios(67)/role`

> "This service doesn't support OData requests in the form '~/entityset/key/action'."

[image: Erro WebAPI OData action]

Comment: What client tool are you using for the testing?

Comment: @JasonSteele [Postman on Chrome Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=pt-br)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ODataActions should always be POST requests. Can you try modifying your code like the following and see if it resolves the issue?

```
[HttpPost, Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
public IQueryable roles([FromODataUri] int key, ODataActionParameters parameters) 
{
    var usuario = (from u in Repositorio.Query<Usuario>()
                where u.Id == key
                select new { u.Email }).SingleOrDefault();
    return Roles.GetRolesForUser(usuario.Email).AsQueryable();
}
```

Also, you need *not* specify the parameter 'key' while building your model as this key is retrieved from the Uri itself. Updated code below:

```
modelBuilder.EntitySet<Usuario>("usuarios");
var entityTypeUsuario = modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>();
var actRoles = entityTypeUsuario.Action("roles");
actRoles.Returns<string[]>();
```

FYI: you can also look at this nice post from Mike about OData actions: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-actions

Comment: In this case it makes sense to be POST, because only retrieves the roles of a user and not make changes on server .
How can I create as GET?

Comment: Ideally your are looking for OData Functions(where you can use GET), which are currently not supported out of the box. Also, if you are expecting any parameters for the action, they would be coming from the body, so you would not be able to use GET. If you are curious, you can take a look at the ActionRoutingConvention in OData to see that we specifically check for POST requests: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http.OData/OData/Routing/Conventions/ActionRoutingConvention.cs

Comment: Why can not I do something like:

`public string[] GetRoles([FromODataUri] int key) {// Code here}`

Comment: you can create your own custom routing convention similar to the link above i provided to achieve this, but when the metadata of the service is exposed it indicates (via the FunctionImport element) that the action is "IsSideEffecting=true" which means that the action can cause side effects where as for OData Functions this value would be 'false'. So, a client seeing the "IsSideEffecting=true" will most probably use "POST" as it knows that this is an action and that it has side effects and that it can post data to change the state.

Comment: GET is not supported!

Design:
Actions will be advertised in payloads just like navigation properties today, with two differences:

You can’t just follow a link to an action; they have side-effects so a POST is required.
Sometime actions need additional parameters too.

From "http://www.odata.org/2011/10/actions-in-odata/"